# Performing a join across multiple heterogenous databases e.g. PostgreSQL and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

There's a project I'm working on, kind of a distributed Database thing.

I started by creating the conceptual schema, and I've partitioned the tables such that I may require to perform joins between tables in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

I know I can write some sort of middleware that will break down the SQL queries and issue sub-queries targeting individual DBs, and them merge the results, but I'd like to do do this using SQL if possible.

My search so far has yielded [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html) (Federated storage engine for MySQL) but it seems to work for MySQL databases.

If it's possible, I'd appreciate some pointer's on what to look at, preferably in Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the postgres side, you can try using a [foreign data wrapper](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrapper) such as `mysql_ftw` ([example](http://blogs.enterprisedb.com/2011/08/01/postgresql-9-1-meet-mysql/)). Queries with joins can then be run through various Postgres clients, such as psql, pgAdmin, [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) (for Python), etc.

Answer (score 1):

It might take some time to set up, but PrestoDB is a valid OpenSource solution to consider.

see https://prestodb.io/

You connect connect to Presto with JDBC, send it the SQL, it interprets the different connections, dispatches to the different sources, then does the final work on the Presto node before returning the result.

Comment: Yes. Presto or Trino will work. I found POC of that https://github.com/pandio-com/trino-demo

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with SQL.

Your options are to write your own "middleware" as you hinted at. To do that in Python, you would use the standard DB-API drivers for both databases and write individual queries; then merge their results. An ORM like sqlalchemy will go a long way to help with that.

The other option is to use an integration layer.  There are many options out there, however, none that I know that are written in Python. [mule esb](http://www.mulesoft.com/), [apache servicemix](http://servicemix.apache.org/), [wso2](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/) and [jboss metamatrix](https://community.jboss.org/en/metamatrix) are some of the more popular ones.

Comment: Postgresql's foreign data wrapper(see Mike Toews' answer above) seems to do what I require. It doesn't seem to be a stable yet, though, so I might fallback to implementing my own middleware if I run into complications.

Answer (score 0):

You can colocate the data on a single RDBMS node (either PostgreSQL or MySQL for example).

Two main approaches

1. Readonly - You might want to use read-replicas of both source systems, then use a process to copy the data to a new writeable converged node; OR
2. Primary - You might chose a primary database of 2. Move the data from one to the primary using a conversion process (eg. ETL or off the shelf table-level replication)

Then you can just run the query on the one RDBMS with JOINs as usual.

BONUS: You can also do log reading from RDBMS that can ship logs through Kafka. You can make it really complex as required.